# Artifactory: "docker service create" does not work with images of 0 byte

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-swarm-mode

`docker service create ...` works even though compressed image size is 0B in Docker Hub. On the other hand, when I use Artifactory as private registry, it fails with `No such image` error. Docker daemons' debug logs say `manifest verification failed for digest ...`

As an example, compressed size of portainer's latest tag and main release tags (1.13.1, 1.13.2, etc.) are 0 B: https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/portainer/tags/

Following command works:

```
docker service create \
  --name portainer \
  --publish 9000:9000 \
  --constraint 'node.role == manager' \
  --mount type=bind,src=//var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock \
  portainer/portainer \
  -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

but following command does not work:

```
docker service create \
  --name portainer \
  --publish 9000:9000 \
  --constraint 'node.role == manager' \
  --mount type=bind,src=//var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock \
  artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer \
  -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Service's state:

```
[myuser@rose1]$ docker service ps --no-trunc  portainer
ID                          NAME                IMAGE                                                                                                                NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR                                                                                                                                 PORTS
gzk05p5x89w9pcvenuyio8pu8   portainer.1         artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40   rose1             Ready               Rejected 2 seconds ago    "No such image: artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40"
fcovqtudbv3zmgo4von01y5wv    \_ portainer.1     artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40   rose1             Shutdown            Rejected 7 seconds ago    "No such image: artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40"
jfy8lr2prypcx72dryse5vmwx    \_ portainer.1     artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40   rose1             Shutdown            Rejected 12 seconds ago   "No such image: artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40"
3ovw7pwgr6srhvqocrqayiuqx    \_ portainer.1     artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40   rose1             Shutdown            Rejected 12 seconds ago   "No such image: artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d0558cd40"
```

Docker daemon's debug logs:

```
...
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.137611299+03:00" level=debug msg="Trying to pull artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer from https://artifactory.mycompany.com v2"
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.169441596+03:00" level=debug msg="task status updated" method="(*Dispatcher).processUpdates" module=dispatcher node.id=xdn6m020ugsnbfqfk2
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.169573572+03:00" level=debug msg="task status updated" method="(*Dispatcher).processUpdates" module=dispatcher node.id=xdn6m020ugsnbfqfk2
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.175689648+03:00" level=debug msg="Pulling ref from V2 registry: artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b0349
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.175757143+03:00" level=error msg="manifest verification failed for digest sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2c6af0ae176c89c92728d4ff0e110d
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.175783178+03:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: manifest verification failed for digest sha256:5393dc7fc9
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.175800969+03:00" level=debug msg="Skipping v1 endpoint https://artifactory.mycompany.com because v2 registry was detected"
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.175878617+03:00" level=debug msg="pull in progress"
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.175909141+03:00" level=error msg="pulling image failed" error="manifest verification failed for digest sha256:5393dc7fc9e93f8ca8b034941a2
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.176596565+03:00" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="No such image: artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer:latest@sha256:5393dc7fc9e93
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.176643801+03:00" level=debug msg="state changed" module="node/agent/taskmanager" node.id=xdn6m020ugsnbfqfk2f5g74jx service.id=ve3ipsb1cx3
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.176882355+03:00" level=debug msg="(*Agent).UpdateTaskStatus" module="node/agent" node.id=xdn6m020ugsnbfqfk2f5g74jx task.id=3rzww5i46b8sv3
Jun 08 12:29:58 rose1 dockerd[14289]: time="2017-06-08T12:29:58.177387272+03:00" level=debug msg="task status reported" module="node/agent" node.id=xdn6m020ugsnbfqfk2f5g74jx
...
```

Artifactory logs:

```
...
2017-06-09 14:00:11,725 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.r.v.r.v.DockerV2VirtualRepoHandler:105) - Fetching docker manifest for repo 'portainer/portainer' and tag 'latest'
2017-06-09 14:00:14,940 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [INFO ] (o.a.r.HttpRepo      :420) - registry-1.docker.io downloading https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/portainer/portainer/manifests/latest 944 bytes
2017-06-09 14:00:14,948 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] [INFO ] (o.a.r.HttpRepo      :433) - registry-1.docker.io downloaded  https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/portainer/portainer/manifests/latest 944 bytes at 125.43 KB/sec
2017-06-09 14:00:15,194 [http-nio-8081-exec-5] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.r.v.r.v.DockerV2VirtualRepoHandler:105) - Fetching docker manifest for repo 'portainer/portainer' and tag 'latest'
2017-06-09 14:00:15,529 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.r.v.r.v.DockerV2VirtualRepoHandler:105) - Fetching docker manifest for repo 'portainer/portainer' and tag 'latest'
2017-06-09 14:00:20,526 [http-nio-8081-exec-8] [INFO ] (o.a.a.d.r.v.r.v.DockerV2VirtualRepoHandler:105) - Fetching docker manifest for repo 'portainer/portainer' and tag 'latest'
...
```

**Update 1:**

`docker pull ...` works properly:

```
docker pull artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer
```

and `docker run ...` also works properly:

```
docker run \ 
  -v /var/lib/docker.sock:/var/lib/docker.sock \
  -p 9000:9000 \
  artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer \
  -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

The problem only exists with swarm mode.

**Update 2:**

As @Tony pointed out, if image is a multi-arch manifest (hence the 0B size) I have issues with Artifactory. For example, all the images under https://hub.docker.com/u/trollin are multi-arch and each tag of each image seem 0 Byte. I can reproduce the same issue with these images & tags. Take `trollin/nginx`, as an example.

Following commands work:

1)

```
docker pull artifactory.mycompany/trollin/nginx
```

2)

```
docker run --name trollin_nginx \
  --publish 9991:80 \
  artifactory.mycompany/trollin/nginx
```

3)

```
docker service create \
  --name trollin_nginx \
  --publish 9991:80 \
  trollin/nginx
```

Following command does not work:

```
docker service create \
  --name trollin_nginx \
  --publish 9991:80 \
  artifactory.mycompany.com/trollin/nginx
```

Comment: Can you run `docker run -v /var/lib/docker.sock:/var/lib/docker.sock -p 9000:9000 artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`? If not, then the problem isn't with swarm and I'd remove that from your debugging steps.

Comment: It works. The problem only exists with swarm mode. I added Update 1.

Comment: Does `docker service create --with-registry-auth ...` make any difference?

Comment: Did not work either.

Comment: In that case, it may be a swarm mode defect. Have a look a the swarmkit issue list to see if anything matches, and if not, open a new issue.

Comment: Have you tried with another image? Something simpler like nginx for example? Portainer image is a multi-arch manifest (hence the 0B size), I'm not sure how you managed to push it onto your own registry.

Comment: @BMitch If it was a swarm mode defect, the same problem would happen with Docker Hub, as well. But the problem only exists with Artifactory. I am not sure whether it is a Artifactory bug or a configuration issue. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks @Tony! You let me point out the core issue. I have added Update 2. For your second part of the comment, I did not push `portainer/portainer` image to Artifactory. When I pull it through Artifactory (artifactory.mycompany.com/portainer/portainer), it somehow pull the image from Docker Hub and store it. I do not know how Artifactory handles multi-arch manifest. But, it seems there is a problem with it, at least while creating swarm services.

Comment: No worries, you might want to report that to the Artifactory project then ;)